# Custom window with WebView does not respond to close action

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, webview, nswindow

So, for my project I needed to have some custom windows, which I created by subclassing NSWindow.
Those also have their own Titlebar Views that display some controls, of of them being the regular close button, hooked up like this:

```
[closeButton setTarget:[self window]];
[closeButton setAction:@selector(close)];
```

Now this works all perfectly fine, except for windows in which I have a WebView. Whenever I load up any Website in the given WebView, the close Button doesn't do anything anymore (before it works fine as well)

I have absolutely no idea, why this is happening, any kind of pointers would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Could the webview be replacing the target/action, or providing a delegate method that denies the close action?

Why don't you set some breakpoints to check the target/action or insert some tracing to print out what they are set to when the web windows are open?

Comment: Yeah, for some reason, the webview seems to unhook the action. For testing i now put a close action in the title bar view which closes the window. When connecting the button to this action nothing gets replaced for some reason. Pretty shitty workaround but does it for now